# How to put metadata in sqlite3-1.3.4-x86-mingw32.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

I perform bundle install but it cannot continue because of sqlite3 it always returns to:

Gem::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/
ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/sqlite3-1.3.4-x86-mingw32.gem
An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` succeeds before bundling.

How will I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

simply run `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` this should fix the issue. Its because the gem is not included it the list of dependencies so running the command will fix it up